# Как использовать WPF в C++ Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, wpf, visual-studio

В Visual Studio есть WPF для C#, но насколько я знаю есть WPF для C++, но никак не могу найти в своей студии данной функции. Можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: [C++/CX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cpp), [C++/WinRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ни то, ни другое к WPF отношение не имеют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF это .NET технология. Поэтому, если Вы хотите с ней работать, то Вам нужен не "обычный" Visual C++, а C++/CLI (вариант Visual C++ для .NET). Так, что при использовании WPF Ваша программа автоматически перестанет быть нативной.

Кроме того, для .NET, насколько я знаю, в Visual C++ из коробки почти нет шаблонов для .NET. Поэтому, в частности для WPF Вам скорее всего придётся всё делать руками или искать сторонний шаблон в сети.

Плюс ряд подводных камней, т.к. направление C++/CLI в последние годы не ососбо развивается.

Вообще для написания GUI в .NET лучше использовать всё-таки C# или VB.NET. А если для программы нужен нативный код, то его всегда можно поместить в dll на "обычном" Visual C++ и импортировать при помощи DllImport.

Comment: В вижуалке точно можно создать xaml с++ проект. Но как-то не приходилось и подробностей не знаю.